# How to implement rules to color range in vega lite?

Tags: vega-lite

In the below Vega-Lite example, I tweaked the color scale in the encoding to be a range of red, white, and green.  However, I would like to change how the scale is bound to the values.  For example, the values that fall between the min value and 16 would go from red to white (heatmap style), and then the values between 16 and the max value go from white to green.

I also included a screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve.  Thank you for any help!

[This is what I'm going for, zero is the static middle point with no negative values showing with any green and no positive values with any red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKoEp.png)

[Vega-Lite Editor Link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUAwBOgtCrVJOcNZkFx+AdxP042ylAjEQAXyWY65-QBEkNQQCeAAQAskgAHkEAKog4dmo6cBBBABQAwgCUQTSyQQDKNmZwCkEA6gCCiiBQcgBmNGRooMQ0cJZNIBCY2mwA1nClNMr0aAAMSl1wOGgAjADMbiARNBAdymzIOWi1SIIQcC6LyNq9+tpwUJhVcLI1yjmNmiDhHfVwgsr6qphwVR4IcAAqrI6F81L93AE4vo2Np7rJdn9PL90L4AlVlqsnoIkEx3uVZGQvKhxiBarDkFd0ABSX6HJTop5vD5gn5IgHA0HoBByEaQ6HoWHwxHuZH6EK8mCuJQ1QSw16tFnoH4IHAAfWQLyUSDIZHOFDZ3IifyhKJAAEcGEhZB51B5SFVoLsUaBtNayCiANogc6fJSWGAiKp6uA3EAAXUW5g9sk+T1txNkDEEgkOhyAA/)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
      "url": "data/seattle-weather.csv"
  },
  "title": "Daily Max Temperatures (C) in Seattle, WA",
  "config": {
      "view": {
          "strokeWidth": 0,
          "step": 13
      },
      "axis": {
          "domain": false
      }
  },
  "mark": "rect",
  "encoding": {
      "x": {
          "field": "date",
          "timeUnit": "date",
          "type": "ordinal",
          "title": "Day",
          "axis": {
              "labelAngle": 0,
              "format": "%e"
          }
      },
      "y": {
          "field": "date",
          "timeUnit": "month",
          "type": "ordinal",
          "title": "Month"
      },
      "color": {
          "field": "temp_max",
          "aggregate": "max",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "scale": {
            "range": [
              "red",
              "white",
              "green"              
            ]
          },
          "legend": {
              "title": null
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share a full working spec and your desired result.

Comment: Hi David, sorry about that, I just edited to try to give a working example in the context of a standard example heatmap for simplicity.   Thanks!

Comment: I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? You can tweak the gradient boundaries using domainMin, Mid and Max.  [image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/seattle-weather.csv"},
  "title": "Daily Max Temperatures (C) in Seattle, WA",
  "config": {"view": {"strokeWidth": 0, "step": 13}, "axis": {"domain": false}},
  "mark": "rect",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "date",
      "timeUnit": "date",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "title": "Day",
      "axis": {"labelAngle": 0, "format": "%e"}
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "date",
      "timeUnit": "month",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "title": "Month"
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "temp_max",
      "aggregate": "max",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {
        "range": ["red", "white", "green"],
        "interpolate": "cubehelix",
        "domainMax": 40,
        "domainMid": 16,
        "domainMin": 0
      },
      "legend": {"title": null}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: WOW, didn't realize that you could manipulate the domain values in the scale properties like that.  Yet now of course as I look back at the vega-lite documentation, it does indeed say that, completely missed it.  Thank you, David!!

Comment: If you need more control, you can set bin boundaries too.